# Totally automating Apache on whatever distro

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, bash, ansible, automation

The problem I'm having seems to be true to all distors but let's assume I use an all-default `debian-stable` (server), and ran `apt update -y`.

Installing, upgrading, restarting as well as enabling or disabling modules in Apache are all non version-agnostic operations and I find this a problem:

1. Installing or upgrading Apache should be `apt upgrade apache1` or `apt upgrade apache2`. It can't be just "apt upgrade apache" with whatever version out there, as with `apt upgrade zip` or `apt upgrade unzip` and so forth.
2. To restart Apache one has to do `systemctl restart apache2` and to enable or disable an Apache module one has to do say `a2enmod http2 deflate expires` or `a2dismod http2 deflate expires`.

### Approaches I considered to deal with that problem

I thought Ansible might help here by transcribing the old installation command with Ansible's `apt` module's `state=latest` option but the [Ansible Apache docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apache2_module_module.html) doesn't include a non version-agnostic syntax of these commands and installs only Apache2 as well, so even when Apache3 comes out, I will still have to **manually release_upgrade it from 2.4 to 3.x** even though I continuously-upgrade basically all the rest of the above-OS software with Ansible (like `zip` and `unzip`).

**1.** Combining Ansible with regex (as in Ansible's apt `apache*` or `systemctl restart apache*`) is still not enough or at least "fragile".

**2.** Even combining Ansible and `tasksel` with and regex:

```
- name: Install latest Apache
  apt: lamp-server^ 
  state: latest

- do stuff and restart Apache
  command:
    args:
      argv:
        - aenmod http2 deflate expires # Non version-agnostic http version;
        - systemctl restart apache*
```

**may not be enough**, as it will still require me for manual changes when Apache 3 or 4 or 5 comes out (say, to existing virtual host files).

### My question

I know it might be an extreme desire but is there a way to install, and totally continuously upgrade Apache (including release_upgrades and virtual host files and so forth) smoothly?

Maybe a communally maintained and well supported **Ansible-Galaxy role** is the correct approach. Maybe I should pick another webserver - I don't know.

### Update per comment

It comes up from a comment by Michael Hampton that this is all Debian specific and that other distros might have version-agnostic ways to install Apache - to be honest, I considered ArchLinux because of its fully rolling-release OS upgrade model. An answer could example a few distros that may suffice the approach I seek in Apache.

Comment: Part of the problem is you're comparing small utilities that have zero configuration such as `zip` and `unzip` with Apache that has non-trivial configuration; it's the configuration that is the complicated part. A major version bump implies there are major (potentially breaking) changes that whatever tool you're using has to be aware of, before you want that major upgrade to occur. Personally I think it'll be a long time before Apache 3+ appears.

Comment: This is all Debian-specific. The software is actually named `httpd`, but Debian inexplicably chose to rename it `apache2` and give it a bunch of nonstandard commands like `a2enmod`. Nobody knows what the future will bring, but fortunately there is no httpd 3.x on the horizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right

> "well supported Ansible-Galaxy role is the correct approach".

I'm looking for contributions to [Apache role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/apache). You might want to suggest other role.